# I created a page with search function using php. when a user inputs a keyword, the info regarding the keyword will be displayed on the same page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

the code is this:

```
<?php 
if ($_GET['partOf']) {

    $_GET['partOf'] = str_replace(' ', '', $_GET['partOf']);
    $posPage = file_get_contents("https://example/example/".$_GET['partOf'].''.''.'');

    $pageArray = explode('example</a></li></ul>
        </div>
        </div>', $posPage);

    $secondPageArray = explode('example', $pageArray[1]);

    $out =  $secondPageArray[0];

}
?>
```

form

```
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="partOf">keyword being searched?</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="partOf" name="partOf" 
 placeholder="ex. keyword">

  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
 </form>
```

now what I would like is if the user types a new keyword the new data will be displayed but my problem is the data is not being displayed since the page URL is different. the output of the input keyword will be like this:

https://example/example/keyword

but the page I would like to put the data has a URL like this:

https://example/example/keyword-word-word-word or

https://example/example/keyword-word-word

is it possible to disregard the -word-word-word so that when the user types a keyword the data will be displayed?

what I want to happen is when the user types that keyword being searched the data for the keyword will displayed on the same page. this data will come from another page/page that I created

I can get the data I want if I put the same exact keyword as the URL that I am getting the data from

example:

keyword being searched: mangoes

to get the data I would need to input in the search as mangoes-green-sweet then submit

what I would like is to arrived at the same result without typing -green-sweet or even -sweet only

Comment: Just explode the string on `-` and use the first element. Something like: `"https://example/example/" . explode('-', $_GET['partOf'])[0]`. However, that means that keywords can't include a `-`.

Comment: thanks for the response. I tried it but it seems to not get the data I want. the URL just changes to [link] (http://example/?partOf=keyword+keyword) but the data is not displayed.. sorry I can't get my head around this I just started learning..

Comment: What URL are you referring to? Please update your question and include your form and a detailed explanation of what you're trying to accomplish (from start to finish). I'm a bit confused. The suggested code is referring to the `file_get_contents()`-url.

Comment: Yes, you can do that, but you need to add a little Javascript to your page (AJAX) so you can async send data to your php script without reloading the page (if I understood your question correctly).

Comment: I was thinking of using javasript (if function) to redirect.. but can't seem to formulate the correct script

Comment: So I changed my code and used ajax and php to do a live search. I put the links in an xml file that is accessed using the php when the user inputs a keyword in the search form. Now my question is, is it possible do explode array so that the URL being called on the xml file will output only the needed strings?